# How can i get most repeated value from Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I get the most repeated value from an Array in javascript?

This is my array

```
var data = [
    { values: "Number of pips" }, 
    { values: 4 }, 
    { values: 4 }, 
    { values: 4 }, 
    { values: 5 }, 
    { values: 2 }, 
    { values: 6 }, 
    { values: 6 },
    { values: 5 }
];
```

The result should be `4`, how can I get this?

I have tried this, taken from [Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array)

```
function mode(array)
{
    if(array.length == 0)
        return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = array[0], maxCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var el = array[i];
        if(modeMap[el] == null)
            modeMap[el] = 1;
        else
            modeMap[el]++;    
        if(modeMap[el] > maxCount)
        {
            maxEl = el;
            maxCount = modeMap[el];
        }
    }
    return maxEl;
}
```

but this is return `6, not 4`.

Comment: I don't believe you have tried anything at all...

Comment: have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440295/extracting-the-most-duplicate-value-from-an-array-in-javascript-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Got This

```
var arr= [{ values: "Number of pips" }, { values: 4 }, { values: 4 }, { values: 4 }, { values: 5 }, { values: 2 }, { values: 6 }, { values: 6 }, { values: 5 }];



    var uniqs = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        uniqs[arr[i].values] = (uniqs[arr[i].values] || 0) + 1;
    }

    var max = { val: arr[0], count: 1 };
    for(var u in uniqs) {
        if(max.count < uniqs[u]) { max = { val: u, count: uniqs[u] }; }
    }

    alert(max.val);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/6mh3e4aq/)

Comment: this will give you the 4

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your attempted code is that you do not have an array of numbers, you have an array of objects. If you want to count the most `values` then you have to use that value, rather than the whole object.

In regards to the code you have attempted, you just need to change the following line:

```
var el = array[i].values;
```

Here is the full code:

```
function mode(array)
{
    if(array.length == 0)
        return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = array[0], maxCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var el = array[i].values;// This is the change.
        if(modeMap[el] == null)
            modeMap[el] = 1;
        else
            modeMap[el]++;  
        if(modeMap[el] > maxCount)
        {
            maxEl = el;
            maxCount = modeMap[el];
        }
    }
    return maxEl;
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/caf4c3fx/)

Answer (score -1):

1. Sort the array. (I assume you can do that... else copy it first on another array)
2. iterate the array and by keeping the previouslyVisited item work this out

Comment: Firstly, don't encourage people to ask questions when they haven't tried to solve the problem themselves. Secondly, your answer doesn't provide a solution. Seriously, you think telling the OP to "work this out" is helpful? I think this would have been better as a comment, then the OP could attempt to code your recommendations

Comment: @musefan I disagree with your "don't encourage people to ask questions when they haven't tried to solve the problem "
I agree my answer could have been a comment.
downgrading me was just nasty

Comment: @Zo72: But SO is against people asking question without showing any attempt to solve the problem, it's in the guides. The minimum is to at least include current code... anyway, that's not why you got the downvote. I downvoted because your answer doesn't provide a solution to the problem, it's just a suggestion on how one might be able to solve the problem

Comment: @musefan given the sketchy question (at the time of my response at least) I gave a sketchy solution. How do I count duplicates in my array ? well sort the array and then iterate over... I thought it was fair...
Anyway you had the right to downvote me so I accept that